# Difference between なくては and なくてはいけない

Tags: meaning, expressions, set-phrases, phrases

What's the exact difference between なくては and なくてはいけない?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## なくてはいけない

- なくては (unless) + いけない (not good) = necessary
- Connects to a verb to mean that you must verb

> 寝{ね}**なくてはいけない**。
>   *I **have to** sleep.*

## なくては

- Doesn't have いけない
- Can imply なくてはいけない on its own, usually in the form of なく**ちゃ**:

  > 行{い}か**なくちゃ**。
  >   *I **gotta** go.* (lit: **If I don't** go.)
- Almost always used with a negative verb, but can also work like this:

  > 契約{けいやく}を守{まも}ってくれ**なくては困{こま}る**。
  >   *You **must** keep to your agreement.* (lit: I'll be **troubled if you can't** keep to your agreement.)
- When used with kanji （**無{な}**くては）, doesnt usually attach *to* a verb and usually defines *what* can't be done:

  > この辞書{じしょ}が**無{な}くては済{す}まされない**。
  >   *I **cannot do without** this dictionary.* <s>(it's the truth)</s>